# ros2 topic echo is not visible as node named _ros2cli_<id>

Tags: ros, tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was following https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Tutorials/Topics/Understanding-ROS2-Topics.html . I called command (I can see msg in terminal, so subscription is working):

```
ros2 topic echo /turtle1/cmd_vel
```

and after that I typed:

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ ros2 node list -a
```

output was:

```
/_ros2cli_daemon_0
/rqt_gui_py_node_3242
/teleop_turtle
/turtlesim
```

My question is were is
*ros2cli*<_id> node subscribed to /turtle1/cmd_vel topic ?

My env details:

```
uname -a
Linux vagrant 5.4.0-81-generic #91-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 15 19:09:17 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

env | grep ROS
ROS_VERSION=2
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3
ROS_DOMAIN_ID=0
ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=0
ROS_DISTRO=galactic
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384828/ros2-topic-echo-is-not-visible-as-node-named-_ros2cli_%3Cid%3E/) by [barginho](https://answers.ros.org/users/81896/barginho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2021-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

UPDATE:

Sorry for bothering You, After OS restart node appeared, please close

---

Originally posted by [barginho](https://answers.ros.org/users/81896/barginho/) with karma: 16 on 2021-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-08-22**:
Please don't close questions, unless they are duplicates or spam.

If you've solved your problem -- regardless of how trivial the solution -- post an answer, then accept it.

That will clearly show the problem was solved.